# Is there a way to create high-resolution images within my ios apps?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage

I have an iOS app that generates various images/drawings, which I then save to the device with UIImage class. The images end up being fairly low resolution - is there a way to force a higher resolution, or even generate a vector to be saved from an iOS app?

**EDIT:** here are some details of how the code runs

To create the image, I create multiple segments - CAShapeLayer()'s with UIBezierPath(). I add those as sublayers to the UIView that has the image created in it, briefly abbreviated so:

```
for i in 0...segmentCounter-1
{
    let path = UIBezierPath() // this is generated in a function with some funky logic for points, colors, etc - UIBezierPath() is a placeholder
    let shapeLayer  = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0.8;
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

After that runs a few times and an image with several layers is created, I use the following code to save the image:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.drawingView.layer.bounds.size, false, 0)

    self.drawingView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.drawingView.layer.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

Comment: Could you please post some sample code? If your creating your own CGContext you should be able to specify the dimensions in points and the scale.

Comment: I posted some code in the edited section above - I'm not explicitly using CGContext ( I don't think, I'm still so new to this) - from my code above, what would you recommend I change?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a “vector” file, the simplest way is to generate a PDF. You can use `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` or `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.  You can find Apple documentation about using this function (and other functions you'll need to also call) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html).

If you want to generate a raster image with more pixels, just pass a larger scale as the last argument to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. The zero you are currently using means “the scale of the primary screen of the current device”, so it's probably either 2 (for a normal Retina screen) or 3 (for an iPhone 6 Plus screen). You can pass any number you want. It doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: That works well, thank you. Last question - is there a maximum value that can be set to? I initially set it to 50 and it threw an fatalerror exception - but when I set it to 10 it worked just fine.

Comment: If your drawing layer's bounds size is 100x100, and you set the scale to 50, you're asking the system to create a 5000x5000 bitmap. Each pixel in the bitmap requires four bytes, so that's a 100 MB bitmap.  (More, actually, because the system likes each row of a bitmap to be a multiple of 64 bytes.) How big is your drawing layer?

Comment: I See, that makes sense. My drawing layer varies in size based on the system that creates it - so on an ipad it's 728.0, y = 728.0 and on an iphone it's 374X374.